# How to drop the decimals from Highcharts 3D columns and tooltip?

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have tried everything I have found in the API for Highcharts, I don't really know why it wont update. If anyone can point me in the right direction as far as how to write this out properly or where this information is located in the API that would be great, thanks for your time.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                        var options = {
                            // basic chart options
                            chart: {
                                height: 300,
                                renderTo: 'container',
                                type: 'column',
                                marginRight: 130,
                                lang: {
                                    thousandsSep: ','
                                },
                                marginBottom: 25,
                                // 3D initialization, comment out for non-3D columns
                                 options3d: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                alpha: 0,
                                                beta: 2,
                                                depth: 50,
                                                viewDistance: 25
                                            }
                            },
                            // main chart title (TOP)
                            title: {
                                text: 'Giving Trends',
                                x: -20 //center
                            },
                            // main chart sub-title (TOP)
                            subtitle: {
                                text: 'By Party of Filer',
                                x: -20
                            },
                            // xAxis title
                            xAxis: {
                                reversed: false,
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Party'
                            },
                                categories: []
                            },
                            // yAxis title
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Dollar Amount'
                                },
                                // chart options for each plotted point
                                plotLines: [{
                                    value: 1,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#66837B'
                                }]
                            },
                            // tooltip on hover options
                            tooltip: {
                                lang: {
                                    thousandsSep: ','
                                },
                                formatter: function() {
                                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                        this.x +': '+ this.y
                                }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                align: 'left',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                x: 0,
                                y: 0,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                            },
                             plotOptions: {
                                bar: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: '#F2C45A'
                                    }
                                },
                                allowDecimals: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                series: {
                                    text: 'Total Dollar Amount',
                                    color: '#66837B',
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    connectNulls: true,
                                    pointWidth: 50
                                },
                                column: {
                                    stacking: 'normal',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || '#F2C45A',

                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: []

                        }

                        Highcharts.setOptions({
                            // sets comma for thousands separator
                            lang: {
                                thousandsSep: ','
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                xDecimals: -2 // If you want to add 2 decimals
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
```

to get rid of decimals from xAxis you can use

```
xAxis:{             
        allowDecimals: false},
```

for tooltip

```
formatter: function() {
return   Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 0);
 }
```

See [an example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/fxc09LjL/)